# Can't format my Raspbian SD Card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I used my RPi for a long time and the OS is a mess. I want to do it from scratch and I want to use the SD Card I got along with the Raspberry with Raspbian pre-installed.

I downloaded the image and tried the below instructions:

http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup
The main issue is that Formatter 4.0 can't format my card. 
Error: The drive is not supported

In windows disk mgr I can see this. I have no option to shrink/expand any of the partitions.
[image]

Tried to delelete everything by DISKPART, but that's also not working:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          111 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online         7535 MB      0 B

DISKPART> SELECT DISK 1

The disk you specified is not valid.

There is no disk selected.

DISKPART>
```

How can I recover my sd card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BOOTICE](http://www.pendriveapps.com/bootice-partition-flash-drive-edit-boot-sector/) solved my issue. You can re-partitionate anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue yesterday and fixed it by formatting with the [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool.shtml)

Just format it with that program and it'll put it all in one partition.